# Where does a body get its energy to heat up when falling from height $h$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy-conservation, collision, dissipation

When a body falls from a height $h$ it loses some energy to the surroundings, is it the energy that is lost to the surroundings that increases its temperature on the remaining energy that is stored in that object that increases its temperature?

Comment: Ultimately, all the kinetic energy of the falling object is transferred to the surroundings, increasing its internal energy.  Only a slight fraction of the kinetic energy increases the internal energy of the object.

Answer (score 2):

When a body falls from height part of its energy is lost due to friction with air.
Note that the temperature is only a measure of the kinetic energy of the molecules of an object.
Due to the effect of friction both the body and the surrounding air are heated since the kinetic energy of the falling body is transferred to the surroundings.

A good example are space shuttles that return to earth atmosphere.
While in space friction is very low since there is no air, but approaching earth, the atmosphere produces friction with the body of the aircraft. The friction heats up the body of the aircraft so much that specific shielding have been developed to protect it. Obviously, the air surrounding the aircraft gets heated too.

The body itself can "store" energy in the sense of potential energy and this will be the maximum amount of energy available to the body during the fall. When the body falls, part of this energy is used to heat the body and the surroundings as in the example above, part will become kinetic energy of the body itself. 
To generate friction, the body has to move first, so you can think at potential energy becoming kinetic and then (in part) heat.

Answer (score 0):

A body that is at some height $h$ has some potential energy due to Earth's gravitational field. When it is dropped, then it will be converted into kinetic energy. Let us say that when there is no air resistance, the kinetic energy just above the ground or when the velocity being maximum is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ or its momentum is $mv$.

But if there is an atmosphere, then during downward motion, it would have collided with many air particles. Due to these collisions, those particles have transferred some of their momentum to the ball. This means the actual momentum of the ball in downward direction is slightly less in this case than when there was no atmosphere. We also know that whenever collisions take place, there is some heat evolved and the kinetic energy seems to have lost. So the thermal energy is coming from the kinetic energy of the ball when it suffered so many collisions. This is why the actual kinetic energy will be less than the ideal value.